# como convertir string a Json para recorrerlo con un for?

Tags: json, api, .net, foreach, jsonarray

cordial saludo para todos.. estoy consumiendo un API:

https://recruiting-api.newshore.es/api/flights/0

Y lo hago con el siguiente metodo:

```
 public async Task<string> GetFlightsVrX(string vr)
        {
           
            string GetAPILink = GetFlyURLBaseLink() + "/" + vr;
            

            client = new HttpClient();
            using var httpResponse = await client.GetAsync(GetAPILink, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            if (httpResponse.Content is null || httpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType?.MediaType != "application/json")
            {
                return null;
            }
            else {
                string APIresp = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return APIresp;
            }
            
        }
```

El metodo funciona perfectamente sin error alguno y retorna un string con los valores requeridos...

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:

- Como hago para recorrer ese string con un for? (Pues para construir esos objetos) el pseudocodigo es el siguiente:

  string RESTDATA = await getAPIDATA.GetFlightsVrX("0");

  ArrayData array = AlgoClaseJson(RESTDATA).convertirAArreglo()

  for(i in array.leng)
  {
  console.log(i);
  }

Lo que necesito es recorrer eso con un for para que imprima algo asi:

0: {"departureStation":"MZL","arrivalStation":"MDE","flightCarrier":"CO","flightNumber":"8001","price":200}
1: {"departureStation":"MZL","arrivalStation":"CTG","flightCarrier":"CO","flightNumber":"8002","price":200}

...

Ayuda soy programador python y no sé nada de .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta pregunta llamó mi atención, ya que es algo que he hecho en par de ocasiones. Permíteme proponerte una solución que acabo de codificar para tu caso, disculpándome de antemano con cualquier lector que encuentre alguna incoherencia en mi código de las 02:00 AM. Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida.

---

Estás cerca de lograrlo, solo necesitas un empuje, para lo cual te escribí esta función tomando como base el bloque de código que expones en tu pregunta:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public async Task<T?> DeserializeFromUrl<T>(string url)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
    {
        return default;
    }

    using var client    = new HttpClient();
          var response  = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
              response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    if (response.Content?.Headers?.ContentType?.MediaType != "application/json")
    {
        return default;
    }

    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString);
}
```

Y acá te dejo un ejemplo de uso:

```
class Fligth
{
    public string? DepartureStation { get; set; }
    public string? ArrivalStation { get; set; }
    public string? FlightCarrier { get; set; }
    public string? FlightNumber { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}

public async void TuMetodoDeLlamada()
{
    var urlApi   = "https://recruiting-api.newshore.es/api/flights/0";
    var flighths = await DeserializeFromUrl<IList<Flight>>(urlApi);

    // Puedes usar IList<Flight>, List<Flight>, Fligth[], etc.

    // Lo recorres con foreach
    foreach (var flight in flights)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(flight.DepartureStation);
        Console.WriteLine(flight.ArrivalStation);
        Console.WriteLine(flight.FlightCarrier);
        Console.WriteLine(flight.FlightNumber);
        Console.WriteLine(flight.Price);
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

---

**Explicación:**

Eres nuevo en .NET, por lo que la explicación podría extenderse demasiado, entonces seré breve.

Primero, empleé el Nuget [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) que debes instalar en tu proyecto desde el manejador de Nugets de Visual Studio o desde el CLI de .NET. Ya `System` y `System.Threading.Tasks` son espacios de nombres de C#.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Segundo, creas tu método de tarea asíncrona para consultar la API, este recibe la url de tu API  y devuelve el valor por defecto del tipo `T` anulable si esta es nula o está vacía. Acá `T` es un tipo genérico anulable, puedes buscar en Google más información sobre esto:

```
public async Task<T?> DeserializeFromUrl<T>(string url)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
    {
        return default;
    }
```

Tercero, acá es prácticamente tu código, solo resumí la instrucción

```
if (httpResponse.Content is null || httpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType?.MediaType != "application/json")
```

a

```
if (response.Content?.Headers?.ContentType?.MediaType != "application/json")
```

y renombré algunas variables:

```
using var client    = new HttpClient();
      var response  = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
          response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

if (response.Content?.Headers?.ContentType?.MediaType != "application/json")
{
    return default;
}

var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Cuarto, usas la función estática `DeserializeObject<T>(string)` de `Newtonsoft.Json` para deserializar (equivale a convertir) tu cadena al objeto de tipo `T` especificado:

```
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString);
}
```

Quinto, necesitas crear un objeto que represente tu dato a deserializar. Para este caso, la url `https://recruiting-api.newshore.es/api/flights/0` que proporcionas contiene lo siguiente:

```
[{"departureStation":"MZL","arrivalStation":"MDE","flightCarrier":"CO","flightNumber":"8001","price":200},{"departureStation":"MZL","arrivalStation":"CTG","flightCarrier":"CO","flightNumber":"8002","price":200},{"departureStation":"PEI","arrivalStation":"BOG","flightCarrier":"CO","flightNumber":"8003","price":200},{"departureStation":"MDE","arrivalStation":"BCN","flightCarrier":"CO","flightNumber":"8004","price":500},{"departureStation":"CTG","arrivalStation":"CAN","flightCarrier":"CO","flightNumber":"8005","price":300},{"departureStation":"BOG","arrivalStation":"MAD","flightCarrier":"CO","flightNumber":"8006","price":500},{"departureStation":"BOG","arrivalStation":"MEX","flightCarrier":"CO","flightNumber":"8007","price":300}]
```

donde los valores son de tipo `string` e `int`. Esto lo sé porque `"departureStation":"BOG"` presenta un valor (`"BOG"`) entre comillas dobles y `"price":500` presenta un valor (`500`) como número entero y no veo más tipos de dato.

Entonces, resumiendo, crearé una clase llamada `Flight`, pero puedes llamarla como quieras:

```
class Fligth
{
    public string? DepartureStation { get; set; }
    public string? ArrivalStation { get; set; }
    public string? FlightCarrier { get; set; }
    public string? FlightNumber { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

recordando siempre que, por nomenclatura, en C# se mantienen los nombres con la primer letra mayúscula a pesar de que en el JSON la primera letra sea minúscula.

Y esta clase es la que usaré para deserializar los objetos JSON en forma de cadena hacia `List<Flight>`, `IList<Flight>`, `Flight[]`, etc.:

```
var urlApi   = "https://recruiting-api.newshore.es/api/flights/0";
var flighths = await DeserializeFromUrl<IList<Flight>>(urlApi);

// Puedes usar IList<Flight>, List<Flight>, Fligth[], etc.

// Lo recorres con foreach
foreach (var flight in flights)
{
    Console.WriteLine(flight.DepartureStation);
    Console.WriteLine(flight.ArrivalStation);
    Console.WriteLine(flight.FlightCarrier);
    Console.WriteLine(flight.FlightNumber);
    Console.WriteLine(flight.Price);
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Si todavía te queda alguna duda, puedes dejar un comentario en mi respuesta y con gusto te proporcionaré cualquier aclaración.